# Can't login, but can register in ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After succesfully registering a random user, the app isn't logging them authomatically. I can't even login after typing in infos in defaulf Login View. It just directs me to Home/Index View and that's all.
I've added AuthorizeAttribute in FilterConfig and an Admin Role

I tried to create plain new example ASP.NET MVC 5 app just to test the default logging, but it didn't work there either. As in previous app it just keeps directing me to Home/Index page

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {

            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Nieprawidłowa próba logowania.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                //var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
                //var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                //await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
                //await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Admin");

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);



                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I'd like to know how do I login the users successfully.

Comment: Someone asked this as a now-deleted answer, so I'll repost their comment here on their behalf: "Could you provide some more information like a snapshot of your database, any logs, error codes etc?"

Comment: What happens when you debug the above code? Does the ("registered") user exist in the database?

Comment: where do you get the value of `result` variable in `POST: /Account/Login` ?

Comment: Are you not seeing login page itself? Does the home page have login button? Can you see login page when you click on login button? What happens when you enter correct username and password in login page?

Comment: Login from login page won't work because you don't actually log them in (you have no call to `SignInManager` within your login action). Registration on the other hand looks ok at first glance. That said, you redirect to Home/Index in your code, so registration redirecting you there is to be expected. Are you sure you're not logged in? What error/behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @John surprisingly, there is no error thrown. After logging I'm being redirected to the Home/Index page, but there is no welcoming sentence in the navbar ("Welcome xyz@admin.com!"). Also, because I've added the AuthorizeAttribute filter in FiltersConfig, I can't enter authorized pages, because it immediately redirects me to the Account/Login page.

Comment: @EdSF  yes, the registered users are visible in the AspNetUsers table. I can see them in the Data View

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya
Are you not seeing login page itself? Does the home page have login button? -- Both login page and login button are visible.
 What happens when you enter correct username and password in login page? -- I got redirected to Home/Index page. I have written more about it in the response to John

Comment: @JericCruz my bad, while deleting comments from code, I accidentialy removed the
{
...
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
...
}
line from POST: /Account/Login action, I'll update the code right away

Comment: Look at the answer by @Bosco below

Comment: @EdSF I've seen it, but after analyzing my code, it turned out, that I accidentally removed this line while deleting comments in the code. It still exists in the original code and cause problems. Sorry about that, I've updated the code above already

Comment: I think we will need more than this Account Controller to help. because the login code block looks correct and since it redirects you to the returnUrl page then it is fine. So can you show the login View and any controller that redirects you to the login and where you added the AuthoriseAttributes?

Comment: Alright, here is my project https://bitbucket.org/Mark_Marecky/timesheet

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, someone would wonder how it is not throwing an error already or how a Build completed.

in your `Account controller` the `Login` [HttpPost], The line below is not there.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

You need to have this line after declaring the variable

```
switch (result)
{
     //ommited block of code
}
```

Comment: Whether or not this is the answer, the tone seems quite snarky and possible violation of the rules of conduct.

Comment: @BattlFrog IMHO, it's not snarky and makes sense given the posted code.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I've accidentally removed this line while deleting comments in code. I updated the code already.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone experience this issue, make sure of the model view, it has to be matched (each property should be rendered in the view) unless if the property is defaulted. Along with checking properties types.

Next, you need to check the controller and the view, ensure that the number of passed properties is correct.

mismatched mapping would cause failure action.

Mostly this would solve the issue.